# how to create a file upload prompt in Google Apps Script

Tags: user-interface, google-apps-script

I have the following use case:

I created a spreadsheet, in which I am trying to create a menu item that lets the user upload a text file from which to process and create a new sheet.

The lines of this text file have the following format:

```
[complexity] [package] [funcName] [absolutePathname]
```

**What do you mean "process"?**

By "processing the file", I mean, getting its contents, preferably as a BLOB or something similar, without uploading to the Drive (this project is for my employer, whose given me other main tasks, and who also has a shared Team Drive), transforming each line of data into the following format:

```
[package]/[filename] [complexity]
```

**The problem**

I already have my own algorithm for transforming the string line to this format, but first, I need to know how to upload the file.

It seems like everything I can find on file uploading, is outdated. For example, [this resource](http://www.googleappsscript.org/user-interface/upload-doc) is using all kinds of Google API functions that [are](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29826476/how-can-i-replace-the-deprecated-docslist-service) [deprecated](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/ui-app).

**User story(ies)**

As a spreadsheet user, 
when I click on custom menu item to upload file
a file upload prompt should appear.

The closest thing that I know of is to act on

```
SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
```

which returns a [Ui](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui). However, there's nothing in here that will easily create a file upload prompt. None of [the available buttons](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/button) are for file upload.

Comment: Am I going to have to [whip out some HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#showmodaldialoguserinterface-title), and if so, how do I get the form output from it?

Comment: A form submit triggers a `doPost()`  function in server code. Alternatively, You can prevent forms from submitting and run your own server code with ``google.script.run``. This is a exact duplicate of [forms](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#forms), were the code in SO.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to present a UI of your making.

As [I'-'I](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8404453/i-i) commented on your question, you can use a combination of conventional HTML Form with client-side and then server-side scripting.

Alternatively, you can leverage the [Google Picker API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#file-open_dialogs). Once uploaded the file will be in Google Drive, and you can process and delete and/or store the source and results. This brings UI consistency with Google Sheets, and some degree of error handling / auditing.

Either UI can either be served as a modal from the menu command or you can trigger it from a sidebar.

Comment: This answer is valid, only if the file to be uploaded is stored on google's servers/drive. OP made no such statement.

Comment: Fair enough. I've clarified the distinction.

Comment: At this stage in the life cycle, I'll settle for uploading to the drive, so long as I have a way to delete it when done.

Comment: *UPDATE*: I found a way to "upload" the text file, getting its contents server side, without creating the file in Google Drive. As soon as I get a full-blown UI dialog up, I'll post what I did here.

Comment: @MikeWarren did you figure it out?